# Micronaut @Scheduled job not running

Tags: gradle, groovy, scheduler, micronaut

I'm working on a existing micronaut application with groovy and gradle, which has a scheduler and is expected to run every 1 minute. Somehow the scheduler doesn't run at all, neither does the application throw any error (just stays silent). I don't see any reason why it shouldn't but i'm a newbie to micronaut and i might be missing something. Any pointer is appreciated, stuck with this issue from a long time now.
*Here is the scheduler class.*

```
 @CompileStatic
 @Singleton
 @Requires(notEnv = "test")
 class CsmTestJob {

 private final CsmTestJobExecutor csmTestJobExecutor

 CsmTestJob(CsmTestJobExecutor csmTestJobExecutor) {
    this.csmTestJobExecutor = csmTestJobExecutor
 }

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = '${feature.job.execute}')
 void executeCsmTests() {
    csmTestJobExecutor.executeCsmTests()
 }
}
```

Here is the `application.yml` file

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: csm
  server:
    port: 8080
    host: 127.0.0.1

feature: 
  job:
    execute: "1m"
```

Comment: If you ended up solving your issue it could be good to leave a comment here for posterity  (and for us who tried to help you : ) with the solution. Might save the next person some time.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this problem running Micronaut in AWS Docker (EC2 Amazon) (I think also reproducible on 1 Core CPU)

Research results:

1. To reproduce run application with `@Scheduler` in Docker with option `--cpus 1`

   docker run --cpus 1 microscheduleapp
2. It looks like Micronaut depends on ForkJoinPool on launch, but default ForkJoinPool will work if you have more than 1 CPU cores. In this condition Micronaut fails to instantiate Scheduled services.
   But manually started scheduled tasks work fine.
3. To fix use ForkJoinPool parallelism option to allow pool to be more than CPU:

   java -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=4 -jar application.jar

Comment: Hi @Dimitry, you are absolutely right that this reproducable with "--cpus 1". However it is not correct that ForkJoinPool will only work with >1 CPUs. But the default constructur creates a pool with size=cpus. Because parts of micronauts initialization process is already claiming a slot in that pool, the io.micronaut.scheduling.processor.ScheduledMethodProcessor is not able to add new taks to the pool to create schedules (deadlock forever).

Comment: thanks @roehrijn, I don't mean ForkJoinPool will not work with cpus=1, I mean it will fail Micronaut to work correctly in this condition, feel free to edit my answer. I was not working on fix PR myself yet. Also hope my answer will save some time for someone else, because I killed a week to get it.

Comment: I just ran into this as well, in my case lost only one day, but yes, the issue is still present in Micronaut 3.5.2, if run scheduled job in a pod with only 1 CPU, it never runs

Answer (score 2):

There have been comments about removing static compilation and removing the dynamic schedule value but I don't think either of those are likely to be relevant.  There isn't enough code shown in the question to know for sure but I suspect your code may be using the wrong `@Singleton` annotation.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/nilambersinghscheduledjob.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/nilambersinghscheduledjob/blob/c7892b556c8564d34d1b3265f53c0f81904150aa/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: nilambersinghscheduledjob
feature:
  job:
    execute: "1m"
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/nilambersinghscheduledjob/blob/c7892b556c8564d34d1b3265f53c0f81904150aa/src/main/groovy/com/example/CsmTestJob.groovy

```
package com.example

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires
import io.micronaut.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import javax.inject.Singleton

@CompileStatic
@Singleton
@Requires(notEnv = "test")
class CsmTestJob {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsmTestJob)
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = '${feature.job.execute}')
    void executeCsmTests() {
        log.debug "CSM Test Job Is Running"
    }
}
```

That all works fine.

Comment: Thankyou !! I'm using javax.inject.Singleton. And my code is almost similar to what you have on github. Still i don't see this issue going away. It's been over 10 days. I'm badly badly stuck.

Comment: "I'm badly badly stuck." - I am sorry about that.  It is difficult to say what is wrong without seeing the project.  If you can recreate the problem in a sample app I would be happy to take a look at it.  If you like, fill out the free consultation request form at  
 https://objectcomputing.com/products/micronaut and we will setup a quick call to work through it.  Happy to help if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue a while back and it turned out that one of the other annotations I had on the class was somehow interfering and preventing the scheduler from running.

I would try removing CompileStatic and also hard coding the schedule as a direct string literal.

Also make sure you are importing `javax.inject.Singleton` because otherwise your reference to `Singleton` will pick the groovy default `groovy.lang.Singleton` which will break micronaut mechanics.

A final thing to try is turning on debug logging and reading through the ton of information printed by micronaut. In my case I could see that there was an issue with bean initialization from the debug log.

I realize this is not a direct solution but figured it's better to give a few potential pointers than none at all.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same situation with Micronaut 3.8.4 running in Kubernetes on AWS.
The problem is related with a [java 17 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274349). Basically, like @Dmitry says, the ForkJoinPool dosn't work with 1 core. The bug was solved in the jdk 19.

Upgrading DockerFile to use openjdk:19-alpine solved the problem without changing the property *-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism*